# Jboss 7.2 - [org.jboss.config] file.encoding - Jboss as windows service

Tags: windows, jboss

I'm facing some issue when trying to set the `file.encoding` for jboss. I am trying to setup the `file.encoding` to `UTF-8` by using the

```
JAVA_OPTS : -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

Whenever I run the jboss as interactive, I can find the below in the `server.log`:

```
file.encoding = UTF-8
```

Whenever the jboss is running as a windows service, I can find the below in `server.log`:

```
file.encoding = Cp1252
```

In `standalone.xml`, I also have defined the below system property (but no luck):

```
<property name="file.encoding" value="UTF-8"/>

<property name="org.apache.catalina.connector.URI_ENCODING" value="UTF-8"/>
```

Would anyone have an idea where we need to do the configuration in order to have `file.encoding = UTF-8` when running jboss as a windows service ?

Answer (score 0):

If you use the script `bin/service.bat` to install JBoss 7.2 as a Windows service then the server is started via `standalone.bat`. This means startup options can be set in `bin/standalone.conf.bat`.

There is a block of JAVA_OPTS assignments in `bin/standalone.conf.bat` to which I appended the following two lines

```
rem # Use UTF-8 as default encoding:
set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8"
```

After restarting the service, the JBoss instance used UTF-8 as default encoding.